# Permission set part of managed package are overwritten when we upgrade package

Tags: apex, permission-sets

When we upgrade managed package on any org then what happens with the existing permission which are part of package:

- Permission sets will be overwritten along with all permissions
- Earlier permission set will be removed and new will be created

Please suggest what happens in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By checking [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm), you can see that permission sets are upgradeable. This means that, as long as your permission set is in your package, it will gain all new permissions specified in your package ("permission sets will be overwritten along with all permissions"). Once you've deleted the permission set from your package, it will remain in the subscriber's org until they (a) uninstall your package, or (b) delete it themselves.

Comment: If i remove some permissions from my permission set then those will be remvoed r=from subscriber's org when package is upgraded ?

Comment: @PraveshMehta Yes, the permission set will perfectly reflect what your package defines for permissions, including any permissions removed or added since the last installed version.

Answer (score 0):

Q. What happens to already existing permission set when we upgrade the manage package in our org? 
A. Permission sets are upgradeable. This means that, as long as your permission set is in your package, it will gain all new permissions specified in your package ("permission sets will be OVERWRITTEN along with all permissions").